# Terraform helm_release destroys all other helm releases

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, kubernetes-helm, terraform-provider-helm

We have three services that we are trying to deploy to a k8s cluster with Terraform helm_release. Each service has something similar to

release.tf

```
resource "helm_release" "someService" {
  count = var.deploy_apps ? 1 : 0
  name = "someService"
  version = "2.1.3"
  namespace = "app"
  timeout = 600
  values = [yamlencode({
    image = {
      tag = var.terraform_version
    }

    envVars = {
      k8env = local.environment
    }
  })]
}
```

variables.tf

```
variable "deploy_apps" {
  type = bool
  default = true
  description = "deploy someService"
}
```

With the only difference being the service name. Each service is in its own Git repo, each repo has its own `variables.tf` file which contains its own `deploy_apps` variable, and they are all deployed to the same namespace.

When any of the services is deployed, it destroys the other two.

How can we prevent that from happening?

Comment: That is the only `helm_release` resource you have in your code? Are the other two also relying on the value of the `deploy_apps` variable?

Comment: @MarkoE Yes that is correct. In each repo, this is the only helm_release resource. They all have their own deploy_apps variable in their own variables.tf.

Comment: Can you add that as well to the question?

Comment: Sorry, I meant can you add the relevant code to the question.

Comment: My suspicion is that all 3 of your terraform configs/repos are using the same backend for storing state, maybe due to copy-paste? That would cause this issue.

Comment: If all repos are using the same variable and value then changing it in one place will have the same effect in other places as well.

Comment: Also, I have a feeling that you left out a rather important piece of information and that is how are you using these resources, are they inside of the same file, is a module call required etc. If all the services have the same logical name it could also be an issue with the terraform state as mentioned by the @user31601.

Comment: @user31601 Spot on. I went through the terraform code the it is a copy-paste issue no doubt. Will rectify it. Thank you!